# Get SUM of COUNTs for several tables

Tags: mysql, sql

OK, so here's what I need :

Let's say we've got a table, e.g. `A` and need to get the number of rows.

In that case we'd `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A`.

Now, what if we have 3 different tables, let's say `A`, `B` and `C`.

How can I get the total number of rows in all three of them?

Comment: you mean count of columns in different tables

Comment: @AnandSomasekhar No, I mean count of *rows*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select (select count(*) from a) + 
       (select count(*) from b) + 
       (select count(*) from c);
```

is the easiest way if you only have 3 counts every time.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
((select count(*) from demo1) +
(select count(*) from demo2) +
(select count(*) from demo3)) as Tbl3;
```

Sql fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d439f8/5

Answer (score 0):

```
select SUM(cnt) from (
select count(*) as cnt from A
union
select count(*) as cnt  from B
union
select count(*) as cnt  from C) as T
```

Comment: Should be `union all`, not just `union`. If two tables happen to have the same number of records one will not be counted as `union` removes duplicates.